# "android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window" on buider.show()

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

From my main `activity`, I need to call an inner class and in a method within the class, I need to show `AlertDialog`. After dismissing it, when the OK button is pressed, forward to Google Play for purchase.

Things work perfectly for most of the times, but for few users it is crashing on `builder.show()` and I can see `"android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException:` Unable to add window" from crash log. Please suggest.

My code is pretty much like this:

```
public class classname1 extends Activity{

  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.<view>); 

    //call the <className1> class to execute
  }

  private class classNamename2 extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {}

    protected void onPostExecute(String result){
      if(page.contains("error")) 
      {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(classname1.this);
        builder.setCancelable(true);
        builder.setMessage("");
        builder.setInverseBackgroundForced(true);
        builder.setNeutralButton("Ok",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton){
            dialog.dismiss();
            if(!<condition>)
            {
              try
              {
                String pl = ""; 

                mHelper.<flow>(<class>.this, SKU, RC_REQUEST, 
                  <listener>, pl);
              }

              catch(Exception e)
              {
                e.printStackTrace();
              }
            }  
          }
        });

        builder.show();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have also seen the error in another alert where I am not forwarding to any other `activity`. It's simple like this:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(classname1.this);
    builder.setCancelable(true);

    //if successful
    builder.setMessage(" ");
    builder.setInverseBackgroundForced(true);
    builder.setNeutralButton("Ok",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton){
            // dialog.dismiss();
                   }
    });
    builder.show();
}
```

Comment: If this is your complete code, do you really need AsyncTask ?

Comment: This is not the complete code, this is quite a big code so I only added the portion here where I am seeing issue from crash report

Comment: okay Good. Usually you can just post the function name and comment that you are doing bunch of stuff there( as you did now). Its easier to understand. :).

Comment: Are you navigating to some other activity from this activity somewhere?

Comment: I made some changes in the code given above. Hope it will help to understand. And yes I am navigating to some other activity from several different areas.

Comment: You've written is comments `//send to some other activity`. I think if you will comment the part where you are going to a new Activity, this error will go away. The error seems to happen because your before dialog is gets completely dismissed, your new activity starts. In the `onPostExecute()`, you have the alert dialog and you are giving the context of the `login` Activity. But you are navigating to the other activity, so the context becomes wrong. Hence you are getting this error! See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15104677/alertdialog-creating-exception-in-android similar question.

Comment: okk I believe I understand the situation now. Thanks for comments.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36961/discussion-between-msi-and-shobhit-puri)

Comment: I made some changes. on dismissing the dialog button, now it will lead the user to Google Play for purchase. Any suggestion for that?

Comment: Is it throwing same error ?

Comment: Actually I never could replicate the error. The app is now published in Google Play Store. And from Developer Console I can see the error from Crash Log, also go some complaints. Which means few users actually got the error.

Comment: Just to mention, I have seen 'Error' in another alert where I am not forwarding to any other activity. It simple like this: AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(login.this);
    builder.setCancelable(true);
    builder.setMessage("");
    builder.setInverseBackgroundForced(true);
    builder.setNeutralButton("Ok",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton){
      // dialog.dismiss();
     }
    });

    builder.show();

   }

Answer (score 296, accepted):

```
android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window"
```

**Problem :**

> This exception occurs when the app is trying to notify the user from
>   the background thread (AsyncTask) by opening a Dialog.
>
> If you are trying to modify the UI from background thread (usually
>   from onPostExecute() of AsyncTask) and if the activity enters
>   finishing stage i.e.) explicitly calling finish(), user pressing home
>   or back button or activity clean up made by Android then you get this
>   error.

**Reason :**

> The reason for this exception is that, as the exception message says,
>   the activity has finished but you are trying to display a dialog with
>   a context of the finished activity. Since there is no window for the
>   dialog to display the android runtime throws this exception.

**Solution:**

> Use `isFinishing()` method which is called by Android to check whether
>   this activity is in the process of finishing: be it explicit finish()
>   call or activity clean up made by Android. By using this method it is
>   very easy to avoid opening dialog from background thread when activity
>   is finishing.
>
> Also maintain a `weak reference` for the activity (and not a strong
>   reference so that activity can be destroyed once not needed) and check
>   if the activity is not finishing before performing any UI using this
>   activity reference (i.e. showing a dialog).

**eg**.

```
private class chkSubscription extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

  private final WeakReference<login> loginActivityWeakRef;

  public chkSubscription (login loginActivity) {
    super();
    this.loginActivityWeakRef= new WeakReference<login >(loginActivity)
  }

  protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    //web service call
  }

  protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    if(page.contains("error")) //when not subscribed
    {
      if (loginActivityWeakRef.get() != null && !loginActivityWeakRef.get().isFinishing()) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(login.this);
        builder.setCancelable(true);
        builder.setMessage(sucObject);
        builder.setInverseBackgroundForced(true);

        builder.setNeutralButton("Ok",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton){
            dialog.dismiss();
          }
        });

        builder.show();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Update :**

**Window Tokens:**

> As its name implies, a window token is a special type of Binder token
>   that the window manager uses to uniquely identify a window in the
>   system. Window tokens are important for security because they make it
>   impossible for malicious applications to draw on top of the windows of
>   other applications. The window manager protects against this by
>   requiring applications to pass their application's window token as
>   part of each request to add or remove a window. If the tokens don't
>   match, the window manager rejects the request and throws a
>   **BadTokenException**. Without window tokens, this necessary
>   identification step wouldn't be possible and the window manager
>   wouldn't be able to protect itself from malicious applications.

**A real-world scenario:**

> When an application starts up for the first time,
>   the **ActivityManagerService** creates a special kind of window token
>   called an application window token, which uniquely identifies the
>   application's top-level container window. The activity manager gives
>   this token to both the application and the window manager, and the
>   application sends the token to the window manager each time it wants
>   to add a new window to the screen. This ensures secure interaction
>   between the application and the window manager (by making it
>   impossible to add windows on top of other applications), and also
>   makes it easy for the activity manager to make direct requests to the
>   window manager.

Comment: 'The blank final field loginActivityWeakRef may not have been initialized' message and tried in this way: private final WeakReference<login> loginActivityWeakRef = new WeakReference<login>(login.this); not sure if it's the right thing to do

Comment: Also I removed the final before WeakReference<login> loginActivityWeakRef as it was showing error in constructor.

Comment: try using  new chkCubscription(this).execute(""); instead of new chkCubscription.execute(""); as you posted above.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36959/discussion-between-msi-and-ritesh-gune)

Comment: I made some changes. on dismissing the dialog button, now it will lead the user to Google Play for purchase. Any suggestion for that?

Comment: It can also be a Toast.

Comment: Dreadful error!! I'm following a tutorial and as @PhilRoggenbuck, my issue was caused by calling a Toast..Show() just before calling the StartActivity(...). To fix it, I moved the toast in the newly called activity instead!

Answer (score 31):

I had dialog showing function:

```
void showDialog(){
    new AlertDialog.Builder(MyActivity.this)
    ...
    .show();
}
```

I was getting this error and i just had to check `isFinishing()` before calling this dialog showing function.

```
if(!isFinishing())
    showDialog();
```

Comment: shouldn't we write `if(!MyActivity.this.isFinishing())`? If it is not right in MyActivity

Comment: Why would Android run any code if it is already finishing? If we follow this solution then imagine how many time we should really use isFinishing to avoid similiar issues.

Comment: @David I think this is missing a few details, such as the dialog being called in a background thread, but I completely agree with your point as it is now.

Comment: Great point, why the heck would I need to check for isFinishing!

Answer (score 9):

The possible reason is the context of the alert dialog. You may be finished that activity so its trying to open in that context but which is already closed.
Try changing the context of that dialog to you first activity beacause it won't be finished till the end.

e.g

rather than this.

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
```

try to use

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(FirstActivity.getInstance()).create();
```

Answer (score 3):

- first you cannot extend AsyncTask without override doInBackground
- second try to create AlterDailog from the builder then call show().

  ```
  private boolean visible = false;
  class chkSubscription extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
  {

      protected void onPostExecute(String result)
      {
          AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
          builder.setCancelable(true);
          builder.setMessage(sucObject);
          builder.setInverseBackgroundForced(true);
          builder.setNeutralButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
              public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton)
              {
                  dialog.dismiss();
              }
          });

          AlertDialog myAlertDialog = builder.create();
          if(visible) myAlertDialog.show();
      }

      @Override
      protected String doInBackground(String... arg0)
      {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          return null;
      }
  }


  @Override
  protected void onResume()
  {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      super.onResume();
      visible = true;
  }

  @Override
  protected void onStop()
  {
      visible = false; 
      super.onStop();
  }
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I actually used the doInBackground method, just didn't mention it here as it's not related to the alert. Regarding adding the builder.create(), it seems working fine, but don't know if it will work fine for everyone. As I I said earlier, my current code also works fine, but only few times for few users it shows the unable to add window issue. Could you please suggest me what could be actual problem in my coding what might causing this?

Comment: in this case the user exits your activity before the onPostExecute get called, so there is no window to hold the dialog, and this causes your application to crash. add flag to onStop to know if your activity is no more visible then don't show the dialog.

Comment: onPostExecute actually gets called, as builder.show() is under a condition when I am checking if the user is not subscribed based on the web service call result from doInBackground(). So if the onPostExecute wasn't called it wouldn't have come upto the builder.show() line.

Comment: onPostExecute is called by default after doInBackground, you cannot call it, and what ever there will be executed.

Comment: ok understand. in that case, when you mentioned 'the user exits your activity before the onPostExecute get called' what does that actually mean? The user navigates to other activity after dismissing the dialog. But isn't builder.show() will be called before if it gets into onClick method under alertdialog.builder? Or is it actually crashing after builder.show() has been executed? because I navigate it to other activity after dismiss? (I have  changed a little bit on my code above for better understanding)

Comment: your async task will continue working after the user navigate from your activity and this will cause builder.show() to crach your application because there is no activity to handle the UI for you.

so your app is pulling data from the web but your activity has been destroyed before you get the data.

Comment: okk I believe I understand the situation now. Thanks for comments.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36960/discussion-between-msi-and-moh-sukhni)

Comment: I made some changes. on dismissing the dialog button, now it will lead the user to Google Play for purchase. Any suggestion for that?

Comment: that's good, do you want to start activity for google play from you app? 
if yes, read this http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/promote/linking.html#android-app

Comment: I have actually published the app in Google Play Store. It seems working fine. I never could replicate the error. But from Developer Console I can see the error from Crash Log, also got some complaints. Which means few users actually facing the issue.

Comment: I have seen this error also in another alert where I am not forwarding to any other activity on dismiss.

Answer (score 1):

I am creating Dialog in `onCreate` and using it with `show` and `hide`. For me the root cause was not dismissing `onBackPressed`, which was finishing the `Home` activity.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle("Really Exit?")
                .setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
                .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, null)
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes,
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int which) {
                                Home.this.finish();
                                return;
                            }
                        }).create().show();
```

I was finishing the Home Activity `onBackPressed` without closing / dismissing my dialogs.

When I dismissed my dialogs the crash disappeared.

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle("Really Exit?")
                .setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
                .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, null)
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes,
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int which) {
                                networkErrorDialog.dismiss() ;
                                homeLocationErrorDialog.dismiss() ;
                                currentLocationErrorDialog.dismiss() ;
                                Home.this.finish();
                                return;
                            }
                        }).create().show();
```

Answer (score 1):

I try this it solved.

```
 AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                   this);
            builder.setCancelable(true);
            builder.setTitle("Opss!!");

            builder.setMessage("You Don't have anough coins to withdraw. ");
            builder.setMessage("Please read the Withdraw rules.");
            builder.setInverseBackgroundForced(true);
            builder.setPositiveButton("OK",
                    (dialog, which) -> dialog.dismiss());
            builder.create().show();
```

Comment: Or in fragment use `requireActivity()` instead of `requireContext()`

Answer (score 0):

In my case I refactored code and put the creation of the Dialog in a separate class. I only handed over the clicked View because a View contains a context object already. This led to the same error message although all ran on the MainThread.

I then switched to handing over the Activity as well and used its context in the dialog creation
-> Everything works now.

```
    fun showDialogToDeletePhoto(baseActivity: BaseActivity, clickedParent: View, deletePhotoClickedListener: DeletePhotoClickedListener) {
        val dialog = AlertDialog.Builder(baseActivity) // <-- here
   .setTitle(baseActivity.getString(R.string.alert_delete_picture_dialog_title))
...
}
```

I , can't format the code snippet properly, sorry :(

Answer (score 0):

I got this error, but mine was coming from the Toasts, not a Dialog.

I have Activity and Fragments in my layout. Code for the Toast was in the Activity class. Fragments gets loaded before the Activity.

I think the Toast code was hit before the Context/Activity finished initializing. I think it was the `getApplicationContext()` in the command                 `Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onMenutItemActionCollapse called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`

Comment: Can you explain this: "Context/Activity finished initializing" , exactly where do you call the toast? I mean in which activity method?

Comment: I called the Toast before Context was finished loading. I'm guessing because Fragments gets loaded before Activities, so I called the Toast in the Fragment. Context is loaded in Activity.

Answer (score 0):

I've read this and a a whole range of other responses and could not solve it for my case; in the end I found that the problem in my case was that when creating the Builder **I used a context retrieved through GetApplicationContext instead of the activity**.

I know this is not the case here, but as this is the first and best thread on this exception I'm posing here in case it's useful to others

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
    public class <class> extends Activity{

    private AlertDialog.Builder builder;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

                setContentView(R.layout.<view>); 

                builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(<class>.this);
                builder.setCancelable(true);
                builder.setMessage(<message>);
                builder.setInverseBackgroundForced(true);

        //call the <className> class to execute
}

    private class <className> extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

    }
    protected void onPostExecute(String result){
        if(page.contains("error")) //when not subscribed
        {   
           if(builder!=null){
                builder.setNeutralButton("Ok",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton){
                    dialog.dismiss();
                        if(!<condition>)
                        {
                        try
                        {
                        String pl = ""; 

                        mHelper.<flow>(<class>.this, SKU, RC_REQUEST, 
                        <listener>, pl);
                        }

                        catch(Exception e)
                        {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }  
                }
            });

            builder.show();
        }
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score -3):

with this globals variables idea,
I saved MainActivity instance in onCreate();
[Android global variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944656/android-global-variable)

```
public class ApplicationController extends Application {

    public static MainActivity this_MainActivity;
}
```

and Open dialog like this. it worked.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Global Var
    globals = (ApplicationController) this.getApplication();
    globals.this_MainActivity = this;
}
```

and in a thread, I open dialog like this.

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(globals.this_MainActivity);
```

1. Open MainActivity
2. Start a thread.
3. Open dialog from thread -> work.
4. Click "Back button"  ( onCreate will be called and remove first MainActivity)
5. New MainActivity will start. ( and save it's instance to globals )
6. Open dialog from first thread --> it will open and work.

: )

Comment: Never keep a static reference to an Activity. It will cause memory leak