# WebView Video FullScreen Mode Crash in some of Android Device When using application context

Tags: android, video, webview

As we all known, Webview may cause memory leak  in some case. So I use the application context to build the webview like `new WebView(getApplicationContext())`.

I need to make the video full screen so I override `WebChromeClient#onShowCustomView()`.After test fews devices, one cause the crash every time pressed the fullscreen icon.

This is the trace:

```
android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:697)
    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:345)
    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:224)
    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:149)
    at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:554)
    at android.widget.MediaController.show(MediaController.java:338)
    at android.webkit.HTML5VideoFullScreen.showControllerInFullScreen(HTML5VideoFullScreen.java:387)
    at android.webkit.HTML5VideoViewProxy$VideoPlayer.end(HTML5VideoViewProxy.java:310)
    at android.webkit.HTML5VideoViewProxy.handleMessage(HTML5VideoViewProxy.java:450)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)`
```

It works well when I used activity to build the webview.

So what's the difference with these android device ?
Is that the core (`Chrome` `Webkit`)  or android version implementation difference to blame ?
How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

If you create a new activity and hide the action bar and add the WebView Tag in your activity xml , you won't face this problem anymore . And you can get full screen mode . But this is a bug in android WebView and Google has pushed a update to solve this bug.