# android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException in Android One

Tags: android

I am getting a "android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException" exception sometimes on launching my application in only android One Micromax device. This doesnot happen in any other device. I have read the question "["android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window" on buider.show()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18662239/android-view-windowmanagerbadtokenexception-unable-to-add-window-on-buider-s)" but still it does not explain why is it happening only in one device that too only sometimes. Any idea what is happening??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: check in the devoloper options if yo have enabled "don't keep activities" :-)

Answer (score 0):

i had this problem in showing a Dialog in DatabaseHandler class, the Dialog needs a Context.
    `ProgressDialog pDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);`
in activity i was called my Class like this
    `DBHandler db = new DBHandler(getApplicationContext());`
this change solved my problem
        `DBHandler db = new DBHandler(MainActivity.this);`

Comment: But why is it only crashing in android One??