# add window bad token when selecting spinner

Tags: android, spinner

I have a custom listview with a spinner as one of the components of the row. I am using fragments so I inflate the layout as follow:

```
this._inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
```

where

```
context = getActivity().getApplicationContext().
```

My layout for the spinner is:

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spTipoDispProteccion"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:textColor="@color/NEGRO"
    android:layout_weight="3.1"
    style="@style/DropDownAltaFacil"
    android:spinnerMode="dialog"
    android:entries="@array/OPCIONES_TIPO_DISP_SEGURIDAD"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" 
/>
```

When I select the spinner ir order to choose a value it crashes and show me the error add window token null. 
I try to pass getActivity() but does not work.

Any idea?

This is my log:

```
11-25 16:47:53.351: E/AndroidRuntime(21116): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-25 16:47:53.351: E/AndroidRuntime(21116):     android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null   is not for an application
11-25 16:47:53.351: E/AndroidRuntime(21116):    at        android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:801)
11-25 16:47:53.351: E/AndroidRuntime(21116):    at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:265)
11-25 16:47:53.351: E/AndroidRuntime(21116):    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:73)
11-25 16:47:53.351: E/AndroidRuntime(21116):    at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:282)
11-25 16:47:53.351: E/AndroidRuntime(21116):    at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:951)
11-25 16:47:53.351: E/AndroidRuntime(21116):    at android.widget.Spinner$DialogPopup.show(Spinner.java:878)
11-25 16:47:53.351: E/AndroidRuntime(21116):    at android.widget.Spinner.performClick(Spinner.java:614)
11-25 16:47:53.351: E/AndroidRuntime(21116):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18190)
11-25 16:47:53.351: E/AndroidRuntime(21116):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
11-25 16:47:53.351: E/AndroidRuntime(21116):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-25 16:47:53.351: E/AndroidRuntime(21116):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:175)
11-25 16:47:53.351: E/AndroidRuntime(21116):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5279)
11-25 16:47:53.351: E/AndroidRuntime(21116):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-25 16:47:53.351: E/AndroidRuntime(21116):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-25 16:47:53.351: E/AndroidRuntime(21116):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
11-25 16:47:53.351: E/AndroidRuntime(21116):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
11-25 16:47:53.351: E/AndroidRuntime(21116):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Can you show us the full logcat?

Comment: Of course, I've just uploaded it

Comment: Simply use `getActivity()` because `getApplicationContext()` is the `Context` of your whole `Application`. Also if you'r using fragments then show full code for that !

Comment: When I use getActivity() the look and feel of the row does not appear the way that I want and other component of the row (switch) crashes.

Comment: read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18662239/android-view-windowmanagerbadtokenexception-unable-to-add-window-on-buider-s#18665887