# Exception in ListPopupWindow in Android

Tags: android

This is my piece of code to show ListPopupWindow

```
listPopupWindow = new ListPopupWindow(this); 
        listPopupWindow.setAnchorView(this.findViewById(android.R.id.content)); 

        final String[]messages = new String[MsgFromApp.getMessages().length];

        final ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, messages); 
        final AdapterView.OnItemClickListener itemClickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() { 
            @Override 
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) { 
                listPopupWindow.dismiss(); 
                listPopupWindow = null;
            } 
        };
        listPopupWindow.setModal(true);     listPopupWindow.setListSelector(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.message)); 
        listPopupWindow.setAdapter(adapter); 
        listPopupWindow.setOnItemClickListener(itemClickListener); 
        listPopupWindow.show();
```

It gives following exception:
Caused by: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?

What's the problem with this? & how to fix this?

Comment: The problem is in line
`listPopupWindow = new ListPopupWindow(this); `

What does "this" refers to? Is in an Activity?

Answer (score 0):

This exception occurs when the app is trying to notify the user from the background thread (AsyncTask) by opening a Dialog. 
Check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18665887/4848308