# app showing error unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?

Tags: android, android-videoview, android-windowmanager

I want to show a video on popup window from service but when I start the service my application crashes show this error : -

```
android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?
```

My code of video player service is here :

```
VideoExtractor VideoExtractor = VideoExtractor.create();
    VideoExtractor.extract("FTD9aA4S5BY").enqueue(new Callback<VideoExtractionResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<YouTubeExtractionResult> call, Response<VideoExtractionResult> response) {
            Log.d(TAG, response.body().getVideoUri().toString());
            final VideoView mVideoview = (VideoView)mView.findViewById(R.id.youtubePlayer);
            mVideoview.setMediaController(new MediaController(PlayerService.this))
            mVideoview.setVideoURI(response.body().getVideoUri());
            mVideoview.start();

            WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
                    PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

            params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
            params.x = 0;
            params.y = 100;
            mWindowManager.addView(mView, params);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<YouTubeExtractionResult> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
```

I'm calling this service from myactivity on resume method.

Error stack of this error is here :

```
android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?
                                                                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:574)
                                                                         at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:310)
                                                                         at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:86)
                                                                         at android.widget.MediaController.show(MediaController.java:379)
                                                                         at android.widget.MediaController.show(MediaController.java:329)
                                                                         at android.widget.VideoView$2.onPrepared(VideoView.java:454)
                                                                         at android.media.MediaPlayer$EventHandler.handleMessage(MediaPlayer.java:2815)
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5539)
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Why I'm getting this error and how to solve this.

Comment: Try the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18662239/android-view-windowmanagerbadtokenexception-unable-to-add-window-on-buider-s/27737641#27737641

Comment: post your activity code

Comment: My error while adding mediacontroller to the video view when I remove this eroor not happening.

Comment: you might be  showing your popup too early, 
Error faced by you arises when we try to add something to Activity, when activity is still not ready

Comment: you need the context of your current activity.

Comment: try changing this code
    mVideoview.setMediaController(new MediaController(PlayerService.this))
to
    mVideoview.setMediaController(new MediaController(this))

Comment: the service itself is already has context and you can use it as a reference

Comment: @dionellorera I already using serviceName.this as a context in the above provided code but still giving same error.

Answer (score 1):

"WindowManager$BadTokenException" this error occur when you using window level object like dialog and before dismiss your activity finished then this error occur. so you should put condition that activity is destroyed or not then please use context.

Comment: But here media controller causing the problem.

Comment: May be it's occur because you are trying to set height at window while it's containing **youtube** object. Please remove these code and try again.