# android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window is not valid; is your activity running?

Tags: android

I try to add dialog in my activity, but in vain, 
Following is my code.

```
    private void saveMissionFile() {
    final String defaultFilename = TextUtils.isEmpty(openedMissionFilename)
            ? FileStream.getWaypointFilename("waypoints")
            : openedMissionFilename;

    final SupportEditInputDialog dialog = SupportEditInputDialog.newInstance(MISSION_FILENAME_DIALOG_TAG,
            getString(R.string.label_enter_filename), defaultFilename, true);
 //       dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), MISSION_FILENAME_DIALOG_TAG);

    dialog.show(MyFirstPlanFirstActivity.this.fragmentManager, MISSION_FILENAME_DIALOG_TAG);


}
```

After I implement app, I got this error than app crushed, what can I do?

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.app.LocalActivityManager$LocalActivityRecord@6ba556f is not valid; is your activity running?
                                                                                    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:679)
                                                                                    at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:342)
                                                                                    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:93)
                                                                                    at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:322)
                                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment.onStart(DialogFragment.java:406)
                                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performStart(Fragment.java:1986)
                                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1061)
                                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1207)
                                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
                                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1572)
                                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:493)
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Comment: you can check this- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18662239/android-view-windowmanagerbadtokenexception-unable-to-add-window-on-buider-s

Comment: It works for me, new AlertDialog.Builder(getParent())
                            .setTitle(R.string.choose_map_tile)
                            .setView(v1)
                             ......
                                }
                            })
                            .show();

Comment: I'm not sure what parameter I should put in dialog.show function.