# Exception android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-alertdialog

I get this error every once in a while and not sure how to fix it.  I read that the context could be destroyed but no REAL answers on how to solve it, especially for my situation.
The error happens below on `Utility.showDialog` in the `onPostExecute` on my `BaseLoadOperation`.  What is the correct way to handle this?

**DataTask.java**

```
public class DataTask extends BaseLoadOperation {

    public DataTask(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }
        @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);
                Utility.showDialog(this.context.getString(R.string.connectionerror), "OK", this.context);
            }
```

**Utility.java**

```
public static void showDialog(String message, String buttonText, Context context, final IDialogCallback callback) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        builder.setMessage(message)
               .setCancelable(true)
               .setPositiveButton(buttonText, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                       if(callback != null)
                       {
                           callback.buttonPress();
                       }
                   }
               });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.show();
        TextView messageText = (TextView)alert.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
        messageText.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

        alert.show();
    }
```

**Exception android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.os.BinderProxy@49fff91 is not valid; is your activity running?**

```
android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView (ViewRootImpl.java:900)
android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView (WindowManagerGlobal.java:342)
android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView (WindowManagerImpl.java:97)
android.app.Dialog.show (Dialog.java:419)
android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show (AlertDialog.java:956)
com.exposure.utilities.Utility.showDialog (Utility.java:196)
com.exposure.utilities.Utility.showDialog (Utility.java:181)
com.exposure.utilities.DataTask.onPostExecute (DataTask.java:44)
```

Comment: Have you [read here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18665887/2910520)?

Comment: I didnt see that one but I see the isFinishing().  Does this just not show a dialog at all?  Isnt the point to show the dialog if possible?

Comment: If the Acitivity is finishing the Context cannot be used anymore to open a dialog. The best thing you could do (IMO) could be a callback in `onPostExecute(...)` which trigger some code in your Activity. Then inside that callback checking if Activity is finishing before proceeding to call `Utility.showDialog(...)`

Comment: Or just catch the exception