# android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException:

Tags: android, android-dialog, android-windowmanager

I got the error on sometimes when showing the custom dialog. I can't trace, Why this error came on sometimes only. Please anyone have idea when this exception happened. Any possible scenario?

**BadTokenException Detail:**

```
android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: 
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView (ViewRootImpl.java:673)
  at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView (WindowManagerGlobal.java:301)
  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView (WindowManagerImpl.java:85)
  at android.app.Dialog.show (Dialog.java:337)
  at com.mydomain.myappname.helpers.dialogs.ApiProgressDialog.show (ApiProgressDialog.java:24)
  at com.mydomain.myappname.ui.activity.SplashActivity.loadUserStatusApi (SplashActivity.java:182)
  at com.mydomain.myappname.ui.activity.SplashActivity.checkIntentForMainActivity (SplashActivity.java:171)
  at com.mydomain.myappname.ui.activity.SplashActivity.access$000 (SplashActivity.java:47)
  at com.mydomain.myappname.ui.activity.SplashActivity$2.run (SplashActivity.java:143)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:739)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:160)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5541)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:372)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:964)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:759)
```

**Code Initialization:**

I called CustomDialog class in my SplashActivity.Class

```
Context context= SplashActivity.this;
ApiProgressDialog apiProgressDialog= new ApiProgressDialog(context);

apiProgressDialog.show();//  here BadTokenException error returns on something
```

Comment: Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18662239/android-view-windowmanagerbadtokenexception-unable-to-add-window-on-buider-s

Answer (score -1):

I you are adding progress bar in background thread then this

```
android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException
```

exception occurs. If you are using `asynkTask` class for some background work than you can't use `progressDialog` or `AleartDialog` in `postexecute` method.

If you want to do something like this you can use `AsynkLoader` class which overrides `loadInbackground` method in which you can perform background work and then implement `LoaderManager.LoaderCallBacks` in your main activity which will override `onLoadfinish()` that will be in `main thread` so for that you can use `dialogbox` or `ProgressBar`