# Error: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException

Tags: android, android-studio, genymotion

I tried to run my app in an genymotion emulator however this is the error that I always get.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  Process: com.example.danicaabinuman.workforce, PID: 2087
  android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.os.BinderProxy@7ee39fa is not valid; is your activity running?
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:679)
      at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:342)
      at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:93)
      at android.widget.Toast$TN.handleShow(Toast.java:434)
      at android.widget.Toast$TN$2.handleMessage(Toast.java:345)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

I tried to run my app to an android mobile and the error did not occur. My app works perfectly fine. Please help me.

Comment: This kind of error is not related to emulator and real device. This issue is concerned with activity life cycle management. I guess some where you are trying to show dialog from finished activity. Please provide more code.

Comment: For more info about this error please check similar answer on https://stackoverflow.com/a/18665887/3787344

Comment: is it android 7.1 ? https://github.com/drakeet/ToastCompat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to show a `Toast` after your activity has already been closed. Do you have a background thread or task that shows the Toast when it finishes? If so, you should check whether the activity has been destroyed prior to showing the toast, by calling `isFinishing()`.