# Displaying a Toast over another app from an Accessibility Service

Tags: android, android-toast, accessibility

I have dealt with a couple of bugs which have driven me nuts for almost a year now.

I am using Android's [Accessibility Services](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService) to perform automated tasks, tapping on buttons, issuing custom gestures and displaying feedback on the screen through Toasts.

For most of the cases, it works like a charm. But I have run through at least two annoying bugs I cannot really solve at the moment.

The first one:

```
Fatal Exception: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.os.BinderProxy@5ff054e is not valid; is your activity running?
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:679)
   at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:342)
   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:93)
   at android.widget.Toast$TN.handleShow(Toast.java:467)
   at android.widget.Toast$TN$2.handleMessage(Toast.java:350)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6138)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:893)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:783)
```

So I’ve made a little bit of research and I have come up with this resource: http://dimitar.me/android-displaying-dialogs-from-background-threads where we are stated that we need to synchronously check that the activity is not finishing before we actually display some Toast / Dialog on top of it.

Thing is: as I am displaying on top of another app's activity, I naturally got no control over it. And sometimes I got the Traceback above without anymore information, resulting in a crash. I cannot even handle the exception.

I have come up with additional clues there: [android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- at Toast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52649353/android-view-windowmanagerbadtokenexception-unable-to-add-window-at-toast/59026454#59026454)

We are told that the issue is well known and fixed after Android 8.0. It's fine, I only got these bugs through Android 7.0 anyway.

And now I have a second issue, targetting Android 9 (maybe other versions) and I cannot really reproduce them:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: View android.widget.LinearLayout{59b180e V.E...... ......ID 0,0-640,296} has already been added to the window manager.
   at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:328)
   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:93)
   at android.widget.Toast$TN.handleShow(Toast.java:499)
   at android.widget.Toast$TN$1.handleMessage(Toast.java:403)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6702)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:911)
```

I am pretty sure that this is also due to the fact that I am displaying some Toast on top of an activity which I do not control.

My question is: Are these bugs due to Android or am I doing anything wrong anywhere? I am not sure that showing code on my end is relevant, as there is nothing coming from my own code from the Tracebacks I got.

More generally: is it okay to display some Toasts on top of activity / apps you do not control?

What would you guys suggest?

Comment: How do you display Toasts using an AccessibilityService? My Toasts seem to not be showing.

Comment: Same as is you were in any activity, just use the applicaton context as first argument to your Toast, like this: `ToastCompat.makeText(applicationContext, "your text here", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)`

Comment: Weird, I don't see my Toasts showing. Probably something wrong with the system, not with the code then. Thanks!

Comment: @huytc What is your Android version?

Comment: I'm currently using Android 10