# BadTokenException in onCreate

Tags: android

I have below crash reported by a user of my app.

```
Caused by android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.os.BinderProxy@56492cc is not valid; is your activity running?
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:567)
       at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:310)
       at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:85)
       at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:319)
       at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:116)
       at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:99)
       at com.my.app.MyActivity.reloadCardView(MyActivity.java:253)
       at com.my.app.MyActivity.refreshTable(MyActivity.java:247)
       at com.my.app.MyActivity.onCreate(MyActivity.java:133)
       ...
       ...
```

I am showing a `ProgressDialog` in in a method invoked from `onCreate()`. So, checking `isFinishing()` looks irrelevant to me.

So, what is the scenario where a crash like this can happen? I couldn't re-create this in my devices. Do I need to check `isFinishing()` before showing a progress dialog, even in `onCreate()`?

Comment: can the first answer in the following link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18662239/android-view-windowmanagerbadtokenexception-unable-to-add-window-on-buider-s help you?

Comment: @CodingLife Since I am showing the dialog from `onCreate()`, it is in the main thread, not in a background thread. I need to know whether `isFinishing()` needs to be checked every time I am showing a dialog, even when I am sure it is not being called from some asynchronous callback.

Comment: can you share the code in onCreate()?

Comment: Do you spawn any thread inside refreshTable() or refreshCardView() method?

Comment: @SonTruong No. Progress dialog is shown in the same thread on which `onCreate()` is called, as seen in the stack trace. There is an asynchronous task just after showing the progress dialog, but it doesn't get executed due to the exception.